# Two simple questions about conditional probability

Tags: probability

I very recently found out about $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)$ while studying probability theory and I've got a couple of questions regarding similar formulas.

Consider the events $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Question $1$

Is the probability that $B$ occures given that $A$ and $C$ have occured denoted $P(B\mid A, C)$ or $P(B\mid A\cup C)$?

Question $2$

Is $P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid C)P(B\mid A,C)$ correct? If so, how can one prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

If you know that $A$ and $C$ have occurred then you have that $A\cap C$ have occurred. So we write $$P(B|A\cap C).$$

**Question 2**

Note that $$P(A\cap B|C)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$$ and $$P(A|C)P(B|A\cap C)=\dfrac{\color{red}{P(A\cap B)}}{P(C)}\dfrac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\color{red}{P(A\cap B)}}.$$ Cancelling terms in red we get the equality.